# c++ passing a pointer to a template function as template

Tags: c++, c++98

I have this `iter` function that takes a pointer to `value_type`, a `size_type`, and a function pointer `fun_type` that is supposed to take a `value_type&` as parameter:

```cpp
template <
    class value_type,
    class size_type,
    class fun_type
> void  iter(value_type *arr, size_type size, fun_type function)
{ while (size--) function(arr[size]); }
```

It works fine until we have a function that has a template, let's say for example we want to use this function:

```cpp
template <
   class T
> void print(const T &value) { std::cout << value << std::endl; }
```

Then we get this compilation error:

```
main.cpp:35:1: error: no matching function for call to 'iter'
iter( tab, 5, print );
^~~~
./iter.hpp:17:8: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'fun_type'
> void  iter(value_type *arr, size_type size, fun_type function)
        ^
main.cpp:36:1: error: no matching function for call to 'iter'
iter( tab2, 5, print );
^~~~
./iter.hpp:17:8: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'fun_type'
> void  iter(value_type *arr, size_type size, fun_type function)
```

How could I make `fun_type` work with every function no matter the template and the return type of the function?

Comment: As an aside C++98 is now 24 years old, it might be time to consider supporting more modern language versions in your codebase.

Comment: @CoryKramer This is for a school project, we have to stick to c++98

Comment: Then I would suggest you lambast the professor for not updating their materials for over two decades :)

Comment: Before C++11 and lambda expressions, I'm not sure if this is something you can do.

Comment: Agreed.  Your use of templates will be (in the very least) crippled from the outset by the poor template compiler support from that time.

Comment: There is a reason C++ keeps adding new versions with new features.

Comment: There are some useful things like `<functional>` and `<type_traits>` that solve all kinds of problems, most of which are only available in C++11 and onward, which would make solving your problem trivial. In fact `iter` would just essentially be `std::for_each` from `<algorithm>`

Comment: I cringe when I look at the code-gymnastics I had to do in order to make template code work 20+ years ago.  Hell even 10 years ago.  I hope they are not trying to teach you that

Comment: What kind of study you are doing? Software archeology? Do you find some tapes by digging? :-) I know that some companies are not able to step forward because they maintain hardware delivered decades ago and this cores are not supported by modern compilers ( we also have such trash in the marked ). But teaching C++98 today... sorry... It is funny for an hour session to see what all has improved, but never for real learning!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `iter` function template requires a *function* for its third template parameter; but `print` (on its own) is *not* a function – it's a function *template*, and the compiler simply cannot deduce what template parameter to use in order to actually create a function … so you need to tell it! Just add the type of the `tab` array/pointer as that template parameter:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int tab[] = { 5,4,3,2,1 };
    iter(tab, 5, print<int>);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, the correction subject is false then, they call it like that in the subject, I guess they want us to not have a third template, but instead pass a `void (*function)(value_type&)`, but this would not work if the function has a return type